# Is it possible to use ClosedXML to read Excel file to Ax 2012?

Tags: excel, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, closedxml

I have used ClosedXML to create an excel file with 3 worksheets from AX 2012 R3.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use ClosedXML to read the excel file back in to AX?

Comment: Do you have any code or anything you've tried?

Comment: Hi @AlexKwitny, nothing as of yet. It was more of a question as to, if it can be done.  Just wondering if anyone has managed to do it.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't see why you couldn't? It might be simpler to wrap everything in an assembly and then reference that from AX if you're set on using it over the regular Excel utilities.

Comment: Could you show how you used ClosedXML to create an Excel file from Ax?

Comment: @FH-Inway I created a DataTable and added the columns and then the data rows as i needed. I then passed that DataTable via ClosedXML to enable me to create the desired Excel file and worksheets. Super easy and creates around 5,000 rows in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: How did you get the data from AX to populate the DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. 
Here is the sample code:

```
ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook     workbook;
ClosedXML.Excel.IXLWorksheet   worksheet;
ClosedXML.Excel.IXLCells       cellsUsed;
ClosedXML.Excel.IXLCell        cell;
System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator;
str                            value;
;

try 
{
    workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(@"YourTestFile.xlsx");
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheet("SomeEpicSheetName");

    cellsUsed = worksheet.CellsUsed();
    enumerator = cellsUsed.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        cell = enumerator.get_Current();
        value = System.Convert::ToString(cell.get_Value());
        info(value);
    }
}
catch
{
    error(AifUtil::getClrErrorMessage());
}
```

This code creates a message in the `InfoLog` for each cell filled with a value. You can use it as a start in any new job after changing the used path and sheet name.

This is my example sheet:

[image]

The output:

[image]